# images from remote server- Phonegap app best practices

Tags: cordova, remote-server

I am going to create a phonegap-jQueryMobile application. In which the data is importing from a remote server using JSON. The data contain images as well. So is there any best practices to do this? 
I mean saving the images in cache or something so that it will improve the performance. I heard about phonegap File API, but I am not sure is it a good practice that I am saving all the images to the cache. Because number of images needs to save into cache may increase as the user uses the app more.

Please let me know a good approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A person that work in Adobe recomend this (use FileTransfer API)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/2sJR_ecLMoY

I am very interested in implementing an image gallery with very high performance continually be caching Internet images.